# Linear function in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-linear function, and let $f(1) = a + bi$ and $f(i) = c + di$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear iff $a-d = b+c = 0$.

- So first of all, I don't understand the rule for our function, what gets mapped here?
- Secondly, isn't the definition of a function being $\mathbb{C}$-linear that there exists an $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ so that $f(\lambda a) = \lambda \cdot f(a)$? What does this have to do with $a-d = b+c = 0$?

Answer (score 2):

- For the first question, $f$ is a map defined on $\mathbb{C}$. Let $z=u+wi$ with $u,w\in\mathbb{R}$. By $\mathbb{R}$-linearity of $f$, 
  $$
  f(u+wi)=f(u\cdot 1+w\cdot i)=u\cdot f(1)+w\cdot f(i).
  $$
- For the second question, suppose $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear, then for each $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $f(\lambda z)=\lambda f(z)$. In particular, one needs
  $$
  a+bi=f(1)=f(-i\cdot i)=-i\cdot f(i)=d-ci
  $$
  which gives $a=d$ and $b=-c$.

Comment: Thank you, I know that a = d and b = -c is equivalent to a - d  = b+ c = 0, but  I currently don't see why. Oh, and there is an "iff" so I have to show another direction right?

Comment: "I currently don't see why"? What part you don't see?

Comment: For the other direction, all you need to do is check the definition of $\mathbb{C}$-linearity.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that

1. A $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ needs to fulfill $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(ax) = af(x)$ for all $a,x \in \mathbb{C}$.
2. A $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ needs to fulfill $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(ax) = af(x)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{C}$.

Your definition says that $1$ is being mapped to some complex number $a+bi$ (where $a$ and $b$ are some real numbers) and $i$ is being mapped to some $c+di$ (where $c$ and $d$ are some real numbers). This fully determines where any point on a complex will be be sent to. Why? By $\mathbb{R}$-linearity. Can you show it?